# Purpose of userdata tag in common_test framework

Tags: erlang

Recently I tried to use erlang's `common_test` framework and faced with such problem.

My aim is to load some data from file in `init_per_suite` and push it across all test cases. But when I save this data directly in `Config`, it spams error messages in test results.
I  found in [documentation](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/common_test/write_test_chapter.html#info_function) such thing:

> userdata
>
> Use this to specify arbitrary data related to the testcase. This data can be retrieved at any time using the ct:userdata/3 utility function.

```
reboot_node() ->
    [
     {userdata,
         [{description,"System Upgrade: RpuAddition Normal RebootNode"},
          {fts,"http://someserver.ericsson.se/test_doc4711.pdf"}]}                  
    ].
```

Seems that this is exactly what I need, but when I inspect `ct:userdata/2` and `ct:userdata/3` it looks wired for me, it expects test directory path and suite name. How should I call it to get my data back?

Answer (score 0):

you can simply append your data to `Config`

```
init_per_suite(Config) ->
    ...
    [{your_data}|Config].
```

Comment: Look at first part, if I put some data in `Config` (i.e. text dictionaries) I will see all this in error report if test case was failed.